# Composer hangs at @php artisan package:discover --ansi

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-forge

I recently did a deploy to Laravel forge and my power went out. When it came back, the deploy failed, and is just hanging on

```
@php artisan package:discover --ansi
```

and it just exist with the following error:

```
Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 137
```

There are no entries in my laravel logs. What I've tried:

1. I've logged into the server and done a manual composer install, but same effect.
2. I've manually deleted the vendor directory and composer.lock and tried a composer install but it had not effect.
3. I've deleted files in bootstrap/cache/* and run composer dump but that didn't work either.

Does anyone know what I can do to fix this? All my deploys are now failing and I can't get my server back up.

Comment: That does not look like an error related to Composer - or does running that command work when you use it without Composer, but no longer when Composer is involved?

Comment: You're right, this was related to artisan but I couldn't get a log that guided me. I found the issue was actually a memory leak in the laravel app itself. Thanks!